# Как вставить необычный фрагмент во ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-fragment, android-viewpager

Как вставить необычный фрагмент во ViewPager? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ViewPager с фрагментами. Адаптер берет данные из массива и на основании этого массива создаются фрагменты:

```
/**
 * Адаптер для ViewPager с шагами
 */
public class StepsAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private List<StepsMenuItem> mSteps;

    public StepsAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<StepsMenuItem> steps) {
        super(fm);
        mSteps = steps;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return StepFragment.newInstance(mSteps.get(position).getFileName());
    }

    /**
     * Возвращает количество шагов
     *
     * @return Количество шагов
     */
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mSteps.size()+1;
    }


}
```

Представим, что в массиве 10 элементов. Мне нужно показывать на 8 позиции не фрагмент StepFragment, а фрагмент WhatNextFragment, при этом остальные фрагменты должны сместиться. В общем получается 11 элементов. Как можно реализовать это наиболее безболезненно и с наименьшим количеством костылей?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if(position != 7) {
            int pos = position;
            if(position > 7) {
                pos--;
            }
            return StepFragment.newInstance(mSteps.get(pos).getFileName());
        } else {
            return WhatNextFragment.newInstance(mSteps.get(position).getFileName());
        }
    }
```

Такое поведение Вам необходимо?